# gnuplot, how to label only certain points?

Tags: conditional-statements, gnuplot, label

I'm using the following `gnuplot` commands to create a plot:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << 'EOF'
set term postscript portrait color enhanced
set output 'out.ps'

plot 'data_file' u 3:2 w points , '' u 3:2:($4!=-3.60 ? $1:'aaa') w labels

EOF
```

where `data_file` looks like this:

```
  O4     -1.20     -0.33     -5.20  
O9.5     -1.10     -0.30     -3.60  
  B0     -1.08     -0.30     -3.25  
B0.5     -1.00     -0.28     -2.60  
B1.5     -0.90     -0.25     -2.10  
B2.5     -0.80     -0.22     -1.50  
  B3     -0.69     -0.20     -1.10
```

I want gnuplot to label **all** points with the strings found in column `1`, **except** the one where column `4` is equal to `-3.60` in which case I want the `aaa` string. What I'm getting is that the `$4=-3.60` data point is being labeled correctly as `aaa`, but the rest are not being labeled **at all**.

---

**Update**: gnuplot has no problem showing **numbers** as labels using the conditional statement, ie: any column but `1` is correctly displayed as a label for each point respecting the conditions imposed. That is, this line displays column `2` (numbres) as point labels respecting the conditional statement:

```
plot 'data_file' u 3:2 w points , '' u 3:2:($4!=-3.60 ? $2:'aaa') w labels
```

**Update 2**: It also has no problem in plotting column `1` as point labels if I plot it as a **whole**, ie **not using** a conditional statement. That is, this line plots correctly **all** the point labels in column `1` (strings):

```
plot 'data_file' u 3:2 w points , '' u 3:2:1 w labels
```

---

So clearly the problem is in using the conditional statement **together** with the strings column. Any of these used separately works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a more clean way maybe, this should work. It seems label can't display a computed number if it isn't turned in a string.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << 'EOF'
set term postscript portrait color enhanced
set output 'out.ps'

plot 'data_file' u 3:2 w points , '' u 3:2:($4!=-3.60 ? sprintf("%d",$1):'aaa') w labels

EOF
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.  All I get is a single label ('aaa') which represents the one label the OP wants to be removed ... doing `sprintf("%d",$1)` only works if the data in column 1 are integers.  doing `sprintf("%s",$1)` doesn't work either.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't have gnuplot around to check, but maybe it's different if the first line of column 1 doesn't contain a number (in that case the whole sprintf thing shouldn't be needed). I confess I did try it on a datafile of mine, and not exactly on the OP's one... I would also try `(($4!=-3.60)? ''.$1:'aaa'` to force string conversion only if needed.

Comment: The following works `($4 ne '-3.60' ? stringcolumn(1):'')`  (stringcolumn is a better way than using string concatenation), but this test is really quite fragile since it is doing a string comparison on `-3.60` instead of a float comparison. (e.g. -3.6 will still put a label on there).  The issue here is that since gnuplot is plotting labels, it is expecting strings in that field (converting column 4 to strings on input it seems).  This also leaves that (empty) string in the output which inflates it.  The best solution is the one I propose below (IMHO) -- just move the filter and it works fine

Comment: Also note that `($4!=-3.60)? ''.$1:'aaa'` produces the same result as your `sprintf` version.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot << 'EOF'
set term postscript portrait color enhanced
set output 'out.ps'
plot 'data_file' u 3:2 w points , \
     '' u (($4 == -3.60)? 1/0 : $3):2:1 w labels

EOF
```

All I do here is set (x) points where the column 4 equals -3.6 to NaN (`1/0`).  Since gnuplot ignores those points, life is good.  I think the problem with your script is that you were filtering a column where gnuplot expects string input -- although I haven't played around with it enough to verify that.  I just switched the filter to a column where gnuplot expects numbers (the x position) and it works just fine.

Comment: As per OP, how to achieve something like this? `using 3:4:(sprintf("%g",($6 eq "swim") ? (tc lt 4):(tc lt 1))) with labels` (I get error here: invalid expression and brackets required...)